# AWS SQS (FIFO) trigger lambda if its not in running state

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sqs-fifo

I want to trigger a AWS lambda from SQS (FIFO), which is successfully done, but according to my use case there will be multiple tenants with there own SQS FIFO queue, for the multiple tenants there will be only one lambda which will be triggered from SQS.

lets say if we have 2 tenants T1 and T2, if the T1 have 2 request which must trigger the lambda for the 1st request the 2nd request should wait for the completion of the 1st one, at the same time for the tenant T2 will have 2 request it should trigger the lambda for the 1'st request and the 2'nd request should wait.

> in short for the different tenants queue's request should trigger the
> lambda simultaneously for there individual request, other request
> should wait in the queue

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using any AWS SDK, or calling Lambda’s service APIs directly? if yes then such utilities provides an option to fetch function's state

Comment: " lambda is not in running state" - what does it mean?

Comment: @PrasanthRajendran you meant that it's available in AWS SDK ? right now am calling directly from AWS console

Comment: @Marcin which means when the lambda is processing the request

Comment: There are numbers ways of invoking "manually" a lambda function. I'm not sure what do you want to achieve, thus difficult to recommend any given way.

Comment: @Marcin  I want to achieve that SQS queue should trigger the lambda when lambda is in idle state, if the lambda is in process of executing request it should not trigger that lambda, hope you got it

Answer (score 1):

If you want only a single lambda function processing your SQS msg, then you can set your function's [reserved concurrency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html) to `1`:

> Reserved concurrency guarantees the **maximum number of concurrent instances** for the function. When a function has reserved concurrency, no other function can use that concurrency.

Comment: one more use case I forgot to mention sorry, there will be different tenant, lets say t1 and t2, if t1 queue has 2 messages which in-turn will trigger the lambda where the first request will be executing and the second request have to wait until the completion of lambda to process that previous request, but at that same time t2 queue has 2 request means the first request should execute parallel along with t1's request and the second one from t2 should wait, hope you got it

Comment: @balajivaishnav Sorry I don't get it. Your question does not provide any information about any tenants. I'm not sure what is your use-case and why you are not including relevant information in the question.

Comment: please check the question added the exact scenario